# What structure should I use in order to solve a query search procedure with multiple linked sets

Tags: python, c++, data-structures, graph, tree

Let *e = {e_1, e_2, e_3,..., e_k}* be a set of entities.

- Every entity `e` **points** to two sets. The first set is the set of  variations *e **--->** {v_1, v_2, v_3,..., v_i}*. The size of the sets are different from one entity to the other.  The second set is the set of facts where *e **--->** {f_1, f_2, f_3,..., f_j}*
- Every fact `f` **points** to a set of links *f **--->** {l_1, l_2, l_3,..., l_m}*. The size of the sets of links are different from one fact to the other.

---

The entities, variations, facts and links are represented by "strings of characters".

**Paris** is an entity its **variation**s are **Paris Hilton**, **Paris New york** etc. Its **facts** are that it's a **city** and it is located **France**. Its **links** are  Washington, D.C., which is the capital of the USA.

---

Suppose that I have a query and I want to search the previous linked sets in order to find if the query exists.

- First I start by searching the `e`s sets. I want to do it step by step.  If the query does not exist in the set`e_1` then I want to search the `v`sets that `e_1` **points** to. The search in the `v`sets is also done step by step. If I can't find the query in the `v_1`set then I have to search the other `v` sets. If the query is not found in any of the `v`sets I have to move to the facts sets. The search is also done step by step. I start with the `f_1` set. If the query is not found in `f_1` I **move down** to the links. If the query is not found in any of the links I **move up** and search the other facts. If the query is not found in any of the facts and their links then I move up the second entity and `e_2` and so on.

---

- How can I model this structure?
- What search strategy should I also use?
- I have to take into consideration time complexity